# How to write upgrade command in the program

Tags: upgrade

Want to upgrade youtube-dl program in my program.
Going to pack youtube-dl and Java and use ProcessBuilder to launch youtube-dl.
Considered using pip but as long as read it's not proper way.

How should I upgrade youtube-dl python scripts in my program?

[Here](https://github.com/iamaturtle113/Jaydle) is my prototype. This is assume you can use youtube-dl command from your linux terminal.

Wanna port to Windows and MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found very nice example code for downloading the latest version on Github.
https://github.com/joejoe2/wav-pcm/blob/master/updatecheck.java

When researching about wav waveform plotting I found this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZnBINrnXI